# If I change the iTunes Test Account country, does the tester have to change their Appstore country as well?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes-store

I was creating iTunes Test Accounts for my beta testers to try out In-App purchases.

When you create the accounts, they ask you for the iTunes Store country. I just left it on US.

One user told me that he had to change to the US store to be able to perform the purchase (he was using the UK one because he lives there).

I'm not sure if the reason he had to do it was:

- Because all testers must change their iTunes stores to the country that I specified when creating their test accounts (US).

or

- Because my In-App purchases are ONLY available in the US store.

Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

**Their iTunes stores to the country** is the appropriate. User can only purchase the app which is available to there country App Store, if you need to purchase app which is not available into your country you need to change the App store to specific counrty.